# Scherrer Formula and interpreting values

Tags: solid-state-physics, computational-physics, crystals, software, x-ray-crystallography

I have created a script in MATLAB that can detect peaks from datas and that can find FWHM of detected peaks. Scripts gives reliable results but crystallites sizes are different a little from this **[online calculator.](http://mahendrakoppolu.blogspot.com.tr/2013/07/online-crystallite-size-calculator.html)**

Link to my data: http://pastebin.com/Ut9YgKGs

Generated physical properties from MATLAB: http://pastebin.com/K0uEZ6Mr

I made all conversion, degree to rad. The problem is that I don't have enough crystallography background to interpret the data. So how can I be sure from the values?

Check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39973073/) if you are interested in script.